# Activity not showing?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to build an app that works as an alarm clock. I implemented everything with help of the AlarmManager and it works fine. But I have one problem, when the alarm rings it starts an Activity which shows a screen with a button and plays a sound. But it shows only a black screen and vibrates + plays the sound and then after that it shows the alarm screen.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wecker);
    laufen = true;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ton); 
    verstanden =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    verstanden.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        finish();
    }
    });
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
    mp.start(); 
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(1000);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

}

What can I do to show the activity and play the sound simultaneously?

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1000);`   when you get rid of this, does it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(1000);` Blocks your UI Thread hence, the black screen shows up.

Use this :

```
new Thread( new Runnable() {
    public void run()  {
        try { 
        // Add loop to play music and vibrate here

        } catch (InterruptedException ie)  {}
    }
) }.start();
```

Comment: It should also be noted that Thread.sleep() should not be used in the UI thread, with only a few exceptions.

Comment: @user2950041 - Which exceptions? I can't think of any.

Answer (score 0):

You have put `Thread.sleep(1000);` in your `onCreate()` method which is on your UI Thread. Your activity's UI only shows up at `onResume()` which is after `onCreate()` so it doesn't get there until your sleep commands are finished. You need to create a new `Thread` and run the vibrator/sleep cycle on that `Thread`. Usage is shown in Shivam Verma's answer.